# Updated guide for TBXML: How to include TBXML in Xcode 5, for iOS 7

Tags: ios, objective-c, xml, xcode, tbxml

I'm having problems including [TBXML](http://www.tbxml.co.uk/) in my project.

1. The [guide](http://www.tbxml.co.uk/TBXML/Guides_-_Include_in_project.html) tells me to include four files, `TBXML.h`, `TBXML.m`, `NSDataAdditions.h`, and `NSDataAdditions.m`, but the latter two are nowhere to be found in [the Github repo](https://github.com/71squared/TBXML).
2. I tried running the sample project [TBXML-Books](https://github.com/71squared/TBXML-Books) in the hopes of copying how TBXML was imported into the project, but it doesn't build successfully in Xcode 5 either. It can't find `libTBXML-iOS.a`.

Anybody help? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Follow this guide for xcode 7.1 and later : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25828208/unknown-type-name-nserror-and-others

Answer (score 7, accepted):

### Including TBXML into your project

1. Get `TBXML.h` and `TBXML.m` from [the Github repo](https://github.com/71squared/TBXML) and add them into your project. Those two are the only files you need.
2. In your project's Target > Build Phases, add the compiler flag `-fno-objc-arc` to `TBXML.m`.

### Loading an XML document

```
TBXML *sourceXML = [[TBXML alloc] initWithXMLFile:@"dictionary.xml" error:nil];
```

You can alloc-init with the other init instance methods, or do it class-method style (I didn't include the deprecated methods):

```
- (id)initWithXMLString:(NSString*)aXMLString error:(NSError **)error;
- (id)initWithXMLData:(NSData*)aData error:(NSError **)error;
- (id)initWithXMLFile:(NSString*)aXMLFile error:(NSError **)error;
- (id)initWithXMLFile:(NSString*)aXMLFile fileExtension:(NSString*)aFileExtension error:(NSError **)error;

+ (id)newTBXMLWithXMLString:(NSString*)aXMLString error:(NSError **)error;
+ (id)newTBXMLWithXMLData:(NSData*)aData error:(NSError **)error;
+ (id)newTBXMLWithXMLFile:(NSString*)aXMLFile error:(NSError **)error;
+ (id)newTBXMLWithXMLFile:(NSString*)aXMLFile fileExtension:(NSString*)aFileExtension error:(NSError **)error;
```

### Sample XML structure

```
<dictionary>
    <entry id="">
        <text></text>
    </entry>

    <entry id="">
        <text></text>
    </entry>
</dictionary>
```

### Extracting elements

```
TBXMLElement *rootElement = sourceXML.rootXMLElement;
TBXMLElement *entryElement = [TBXML childElementNamed:@"entry" parentElement:rootElement];
```

### Extracting attributes

```
NSString *id = [TBXML valueOfAttributeNamed:@"id" forElement:entryElement];
```

### Extracting element text

```
TBXMLElement *textElement = [TBXML childElementNamed:@"text" parentElement:entryElement];
NSString *text = [TBXML textForElement:textElement];
```

### Traversing unknown elements/attributes

If I wanted to print out the text inside every `<text>` element inside every `<entry>`, this is what I'll do:

```
TBXML *sourceXML = [[TBXML alloc] initWithXMLFile:@"dictionary.xml" error:nil];
TBXMLElement *rootElement = sourceXML.rootXMLElement;
TBXMLElement *entryElement = [TBXML childElementNamed:@"entry" parentElement:rootElement];

do {
    TBXMLElement *textElement = [TBXML childElementNamed:@"text" parentElement:entryElement];
    NSString *word = [TBXML textForElement:textElement];
    NSLog(@"%@", word);
} while ((entryElement = entryElement->nextSibling) != nil);
```

I haven't personally tried out traversing the attributes but I assume you can do something like `entryElement->firstAttribute`, as shown in [the old guide](http://www.tbxml.co.uk/TBXML/Guides_-_Traversing_Unknown_elements___attributes.html). You can also just look at `TBXML.h` for how to go about it.

Comment: How does one 'add the compiler flag? I go to the Build Phases and see the file - then what? I now see 'Compiler Flags' and the -fno-objc-arc to the far right. But the red '!' is still there with the same error. Is there another set?

Comment: @user3741598 For Xcode 5, go to build settings and search for "Apple LLVM 5.0 - Language - Objective-C." Then, set **Objective-C Automatic Reference Counting** to NO in your target project.

Comment: Thanks. I did get past this in a new, clean project (then ran into a known TBXML issue with a bogus 'using stringWithString... redundant' warning (which is obviously more than a warning since the call fails to read the XML :-) ). But will try your advice on the old proj.

Comment: The above solution is not working for me in Xcode 7.1.

Comment: Use this guide for xcode 7 or latter : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25828208/unknown-type-name-nserror-and-others

Comment: what to do if you don't know the text tags? I mean if those are dynamically created from server itself & may be only one tag or multiple tags like text

Answer (score 2):

I'd suggest using cocoapods if you aren't already.

http://cocoapods.org/?q=tbxml